# xI Inverter Schematic Symbol - What is it?

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, schematics, symbol, block-diagram

Looking at the block diagram for the UC3637 and I'm unsure what this block is that takes +Vth and turns it into current Is. Does anyone know the name of this sub circuit? Thanks

[image: Block Diagram showing inverter with xI or xl on it]

Comment: IMHO it's a x1 buffer. Then Is is current mirrored in various places. Read the description for Iset and it should be clear

Comment: You are right. From the datasheet "The +VTH terminal voltage is buffered internally and also applied to the lSET terminal to develop the capacitor charging current through RT"